# google cloud api unknown name "body_resource"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer

I want to get the IAM policy for a user using

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/getIamPolicy

When I enter a userid into the resource field though, I get

> {
>     "error": {
>       "code": 400,
>       "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"body_resource\": Cannot find field.",
>       "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
>       "details": [
>         {
>           "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
>           "fieldViolations": [
>             {
>               "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"body_resource\": Cannot find field."
>             }
>           ]
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   }

What should I put in the request body to get the IAM policy for this user? Or is the error wrong and Users just dont have resource policies like this?

EDIT: To be clear, I get this error no matter what I put in the resource field

Comment: Try the api explorer: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/policy/m/cloudresourcemanager/v1/cloudresourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy I get the same error, I think it's broken at the moment

Comment: Make this an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think right now the UI for this API is broken and doesn't work from the browser, I get the same error.

You can however try calling it from the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/policy/m/cloudresourcemanager/v1/cloudresourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy), or by making the call using the api client libraries as shown in the examples at the bottom of the page you linked.

Answer (score 1):

The in-page explorer did have a bug, but the fix is rolling out now.

This was caused by an issue with how the GAPI library calls APIs with a parameter called 'resource', so it should only have affected pages with such a parameter in their method.